# SQL search query on most relevant records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a table with 6 columns and I want to perform a select query based on all 6 columns, but one column's data is mistyped/incorrect and I get no data returned. What could be used to still have my data returned even though some data is incorrect, but I still want most relevant records to be returned?

Comment: Would need more information / schema / sql statement, but the answer is probably going to involve (x OR y) in your predicates to handle the bad data. Without more information though, this question is somewhat unanswerable.

Comment: There is no in-built function (other than SOUNDEX) to do this and it's not a simple task. An option would be using custom CLR functions that implement fuzzy-like string logics, like Levenstein or Smith Waterman.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how much this can help you, But you can give a try using **SOUNDEX** function in SQL server.

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for information on **SOUNDEX** Function